# Max and Min Values of Roll, Pitch and Yaw of the capture motion of iPhone 

Tags: iphone, xcode, motion

This proram is to detect values of the gyroscope (Roll, Pitch and Yaw).

Please i want to know what is the max and Min values of Roll, Pitch and Yaw. (Values of Gyroscope)

---

Initialising :

> [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:0.2f];
>
> [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
>
> motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
>
> motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01; // 100Hz
>
> motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01;  // 100Hz
>
> [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];

---

> motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll   // Max and Min Value ?
>
> motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw    // Max and Min Value ?
>
> motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.Pitch  // Max and Min Value ?

And how to pass to the Values -> Degree ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly put a little bit more effort into your question and add one or two complete sentences to make it understandable?

Comment: Sorry for my english, i am Frensh, ask me question and i will try to explaine it for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution :

if you put

```
#define degrees(x) (180 * x / M_PI)
```

Then the values in Degree :

```
Vroll = degrees(motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll);
Vyaw  = degrees(motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw);
Vpitch= degrees(motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch);
```

So :

> Vroll Min : -180°, Max : 180°
>
> Vyaw  Min : -180°, Max : 180°
>
> Vpitch Min : -90°, Max : 90°

Thanks stackoverflow :)